# Fetch ignoring ok field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-http

When I'm trying to fetch data from API with `use-http` hook, I'm checking if the response is ok, I'm not getting the expected result even if the data comes fine

```
const {
        get,
        response,
        loading,
        error
    } = useFetch(getBooksUrl);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        get()
    }, []);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(response.ok){
            response
            .json()
            .then(val => console.log(val));
        } else {
            console.log(response);
        }
    }, [response]);
```

In the end, I'm always hitting the `else` condition

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` your `get()` method, as it is async. So first, when your component mounts:

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    await get();
  })();
}, []);
```

Now, in your `useEffect` hook, `response.ok` should be truthy.

Comment: For some reason, it's still falsy

Comment: So not sure, check the docs here https://use-http.com/#/, and be sure that your api is returning truthy values!